# Keras: Many batch sizes fail

Tags: python, keras

I am working on generalizing the inputs to the [sample variational autoencoder in the Keras repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py), but seem to have made some elementary mistakes. In particular, only certain batch sizes work for the model below:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import mse
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

# reparameterization trick
# instead of sampling from Q(z|X), sample epsilon = N(0,I)
# z = z_mean + sqrt(var) * epsilon
def sampling(args):
  z_mean, z_log_var = args
  batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
  dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
  # by default, random_normal has mean = 0 and std = 1.0
  epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
  return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

# network parameters
original_dim = 45
input_shape = (original_dim, )
intermediate_dim = 512
latent_dim = 2

# VAE model = encoder + decoder
# build encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = Reshape((original_dim,))(inputs)
x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(x)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')

# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
x = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x)
outputs = Reshape(input_shape)(x)
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')
vae.add_loss(mse(inputs, outputs))
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')

x_train = np.random.rand(1000, 45)
vae.fit(x_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10) # works, while 23 fails
```

Can anyone help me understand why some batch sizes fail (e.g. 23)? I'd be grateful for any insights others can offer on this question.

Comment: Removing the reshape layers appears to fix this, though I'm not sure why yet

Comment: What error did you get? If all larger batch sizes fail it could be that you're running out of memory (seems unlikely with only 1000 floats). It could be a problem to have different batch sizes, so when data%batch_size != 0, some batches will be shorter.

Comment: Yes, I believe the modulo / remainder is exactly the problem. Is there a general solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have unequal batch sizes if `data%batch_size != 0`.You can solve your problem by changing your code to:

```py
x_train = np.random.rand(1000, 45)
batch_size = 23
vae.fit(x_train, epochs=100, steps_per_epoch = x_train.size//batch_size)
```

This results in all batches having the same size, [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit) is the documentation of `fit` with its attributes.

Comment: Amazing! I hadn't seen `steps_per_epoch`. I thought Keras was smart enough to treat batch sizes that aren't even divisors of one's input data size. This seems like a perfect workaround. Thanks very much!